# Local conditional variable thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to rewrite without duplication something like this:

```
<span th:if=${userRole == 'ADMIN'} style="display:inline;"> // display property for logic only 
    <div> ... </div>
</span>
<span th:unless=${userRole == 'ADMIN'} style="display:none;"> 
    <div> ... </div>
</span>
```

In the 2nd case we have the same code, just hidden. This way I have duplicated code. It would be better to have a variable change it's value to either "none" or visible" and use that on a single tag.

How can I do it without duplication, implementing the following logic:

```
$variable = "display: none;"
th:if=${userRole == 'ADMIN'} $variable="display: visible"

<span style="display: $variable;"> 
    <div> ... </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ternary operator` (`? :`) to do it in one line without duplication.

```
th:style="${userRole} == 'ADMIN' ? 'display:inline' : 'display:none'"
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's exactly what I was looking for in this example. Logic is obvious, but thymeleaf syntax still giving me headaches, learning it now.